# Google sheets api (java) - how to access cell's strikethrough value

Tags: java, google-sheets

I am writing a java application that interacts with the google sheets api. I have a method that returns the object for a given cell, and then writes a blank string to that cell. The part I am missing is that I want to write to the cell only if its current contents have strikethrough formatting. If I understand the documentation, the object I have returned should contain a textFormat object that contains a boolean value for strikethrough. I have no idea how I can access that value for my condition, however. Can someone advise please?

Note: I am a beginner.

```
public static void deleteStrikethroughValue (String spreadsheetId, int sheetId, String text, int column, int row, String inputTableRange) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        
        //returns cell object
        List<List<Object>> tableContents = SheetsQuickstart.getValues(inputTableRange);
        int sheet2RowNumber = 0;
        Object cellValue = "";
        for (List row2 : tableContents) {
            sheet2RowNumber = sheet2RowNumber+1;
            if (sheet2RowNumber == row) {
                cellValue = row2.get(column);
            }
        }
        
        //writes to cell
        
        if (XXXXXX) {
            
            Sheets service = SheetsQuickstart.getSheetsService();
            List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
    
              List<CellData> values = new ArrayList<CellData>();
    
              values.add(new CellData()
                        .setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue()
                                .setStringValue("")));
                requests.add(new Request()
                        .setUpdateCells(new UpdateCellsRequest()
                                .setStart(new GridCoordinate()
                                        .setSheetId(sheetId)
                                        .setRowIndex(row)
                                        .setColumnIndex(column))
                                .setRows(Arrays.asList(
                                        new RowData().setValues(values)))
                                .setFields("userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor")));
    
                BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
                        .setRequests(requests);
                service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, batchUpdateRequest)
                        .execute();
            
        }
        
        else {
            System.out.println("did not match");
        }
    
}
```

Comment: By **XXXXXX** you mean that strikthrough format comparison should be here? Is it mandatory for your application?

Comment: Yes condition XXXXX needs to check cellValue for strikethrough format. It is mandatory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In order to get the strikethrough value you should use Sheets API Method: spreadsheets.get

By using the [Quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) I made the following changes to get the **strikethrough** value from a cell:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.Spreadsheet;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.Sheet;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.GridData;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.RowData;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.CellData;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.CellFormat;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.TextFormat;


import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).setCallbackPath("/").build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    /**
     * Google sheets api (java) - how to access cell's strikethrough value
     *
     */
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        /* HERE STARTS YOUR CODE */
        String spreadsheetId = "ID";
        List<String> ranges = new ArrayList<>();
        ranges.add("A1:B2");
        Spreadsheet spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets()
                .get(spreadsheetId)
                .setRanges(ranges)
                .setIncludeGridData(true)
                .execute();

        // 0 represents the first Sheet in your spreadsheet
        int sheetIndex = 0;
        Sheet sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets().get(sheetIndex); 
        GridData gridData = sheet.getData().get(0);

        // 1 represents the row 2 in your sheet
        int row = 1;
        RowData rowData = gridData.getRowData().get(row);
        
        // 1 represents the column B
        int column = 1;
        CellData cellData = rowData.getValues().get(column);

        // This will print the First sheet on my
        // spreadsheet cell B2 strikethrough value
        System.out.println(
          cellData
            .getEffectiveFormat()
            .getTextFormat()
            .getStrikethrough()
        );
        /* HERE ENDS YOUR CODE */
    }
}
```

Where `cellData.getEffectiveFormat().getTextFormat().getStrikethrough()` on **line 102** will print the boolean value (strikethrough).

### Sheets API References

[Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

[Resource: Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet)

[Resource: Sheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets)

[Resource: GridData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#GridData)

[Resource: RowData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#RowData)

[Resource: CellData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellData)

[Resource: CellFormat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellFormat)

[Resource: TextFormat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#TextFormat)

### Google Sheets Java library references

[Class Sheets.Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/Sheets.Spreadsheets.html)

[Class Sheets.Spreadsheets.Get](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/Sheets.Spreadsheets.Get.html)

[Sheets.Spreadsheets.Get setRanges](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/Sheets.Spreadsheets.Get.html#setRanges-java.util.List-)

[Sheets.Spreadsheets.Get setIncludeGridData](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/Sheets.Spreadsheets.Get.html#setIncludeGridData-java.lang.Boolean-)

[Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/Sheet.html)

[Class GridData](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/GridData.html)

[Class RowData](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/RowData.html)

[Class CellData](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/CellData.html)

[Class CellFormat](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/CellFormat.html)

[Class TextFormat](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/TextFormat.html)